# Jquery loading twice in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have found out JQuery is loading twice on my Wordpress website and is causing some plugins to break. I have done some research and think I need to remove some JQuery code from the `header.php` file, and then insert some new JQuery code into the `functions.php` file. Trouble is I am not exactly sure what code to remove/add. Can anyone help me stop JQuery running twice?

Comment: if it is a jquery library file then add it once at header.

Comment: post here or via pastebin header.php code

Answer (score 0):

To remove the default WordPress jQuery file you can use the following:

```
function remove_jquery(){
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','remove_jquery');
```

That should deregister and dequeue the native jQuery file and keep the one that you have in your header.php file.

Comment: do i add this in my function.php file?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't respond sooner.  I didn't get a notice that you had replied.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dequeue_script() {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' ); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_script', 100);
```

Comment: do i add this to my header.php file?